# iPhone App Product Name

Tags: iphone, xcodebuild

I am having problem with the XCode->Project->Edit Active Target "projectname" setting

I am trying to set the "Product Name" as "My App" , but while running the app in the device. I am getting an error as Illegal Character present in Product Name.

I even tried with - and _ (My-App , My_App) but none of these works.

However it works fine in the simulator.

What may be the reason?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the exact error? What do you have as "Bundle Identifier" in your Info.plist?

Comment: I am getting error like this
<com.apple.tools.product-pkg-utility>: error: CFBundleIdentifier ‘com.qdideas.My_App’ contains illegal character ‘_’

Comment: Having you tried to set "MY App" for ALL CONFIGURATIONS under Target>Preferences>Build>Packaging?

Comment: I have tried all configurations also but without a luck.

someone suggested to remove the space , its working now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default Xcode used the Product Name as part of the "Bundle identifier".  "Bundle identifier" must conform to URL rules and be composed of only characters allowed in URLs.  The legal characters are letters, numbers, "-", ".".  In short remove the space in the "Bundle identifier": "MyApp".